# Xcode UITesting - How to press a Button inside a custom tableSectionFooterView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, uitest

I've a table with multiple sections. Each section has a custom footer view, with a button inside.
From the UITests, I can't manage to make the automated process press the button.

I've tried manually writing the tap() action and also tried by recording the test in Xcode, without any luck.

What I've been trying:

```
isAccessibilityElement = true/false
accessibilityIdentifier = ...
accessibilityLabel = ...
```

to the custom footer view, and also to the UIButton.

This is what Xcode prints when recording the test at the moment of pressing the button:

```
app.otherElements["ACTIVITY_VIEW"].tables["ACTIVITY_TABLE_VIEW"].children(matching: .other)["FOOTER_VIEW"].children(matching: .other)["FOOTER_VIEW"].tap()
```

Also, when printing the results of **XCUIApplication().debugDescription** I only see the following for the section:

```
Other, 0x600002251880, {{0.0, 272.0}, {414.0, 68.0}}, identifier: 'FOOTER_VIEW'
   Other, 0x60000224bc60, {{0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}}
```

I'm not able to see there the button, even if I set an accessibilityIdentifier to it.

Comment: remove accessibility for footer and add for button

Comment: @canister_exister already tried! both at the same time, one at a time...no luck.

Comment: Have you run the tests on a simulator or on a device? Just to make sure you might find your element through the accesibilityIdentifier in both or one of the cases.

Comment: Try to enable the accessibility inspector in Simulator Settings app -> General -> Accessibility and check if you can select the button and inspect its traits

Comment: Ideally you should set the `accessibilityIdentifier` to the UIButton you are interested in and set the `isAccessibilityElement = false` to your Footer View.

Comment: If you have any of this elements in a storyboard, just make sure to uncheck `Accessibility` for the views such as the FooterView and the Button in case they are in the Storyboard and then programmatically set isAccessibilityElement = false to your footer view.

Comment: hey thanks @denis_lor! Please, see the answer I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

It was a problem with the mock data. The tableView was confusing the rows between the different sections.

Setting *accessibilityIdentifier* to the target button is enough.